# Python: Is there a way to pickle highly-recursive objects without using 'setrecursionlimit'?

Tags: python, recursion, pickle, ranking

to make a bit of context, I am currently trying to use the [whole-history-rating](https://github.com/pfmonville/whole_history_rating) package which allows us to rank players in a 1v1 game (or sport) after we added all the games already played (similar to the ELO system).

So in my project, I had to add about 1 700 000 games, and in order to save the object I used the method save_base(path) from the whole-history-rating package which in fact uses pickle as shown below :

```
def save_base(self, path):
    """saves the current state of the base to a file at "path"
        
    Args:
        path (str): the path where to save the base
    """
    pickle.dump([self.players,self.games,self.config["w2"]], open(path, 'wb'))
```

But it raises the following error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object`

I have tried to increase the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit`, but the error persists until I reach my machine limit which results in a crash of Python.

So How could I overcome this problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post which function(s) it is recursing?

Comment: I think it might be pickle.dump which is recursing